# Oxidshop - Get a product url

Tags: oxid

I am working on Oxidshop tpl files and want to know how can I get a url for a particular product so that I can create an anchor tag linking to the product in a tpl file?

Answer (score 1):

there are basically two options:

- `[{$product->getMainLink()}]`
- `[{$product->getLink()}]`

The first one gives you the general main link to the product in its main category http://your-shop.tld/category/article.html
The second one should give you the link according to the context, e.g. if you are browsing the articles from a particular manufacturer, you should get http://your-shop.tld/manufacturer/article.html